# Extract number of number

Tags: c

How to extract a number that is contained in another number using a macro not a function.

Example Pseudocode:

```
#define extract_number(int number, // original number
                   int pos, // start position from behind (1 == first digit)
                   int len) // count of digits
{
    ...
}

main() {
    int number = 0;
    int result = 0;

    number = 123456789;
    result = extract_number(number, 2, 3); // result: 678

    number = 987123456;
    result = extract_number(number, 4, 4); // result: 7123
}
```

EDIT 21.09.2016:
What I do atm is the following:

```
int number = 123456789;
int result = number / 10 % 1000;
```

The version using a function posted by @Frzn Flms is the way I would have done it in a function. Is there a way using a macro to do it at compile time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly a write my code request, not a question. Please read [Ask] page first. :)

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: You mean find the prime factors of that number?

Comment: http://ideone.com/g4O8Ry

Comment: You can not access the contents of the variable the phase of  preprocessor (in compile time).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I know that the preprocess can't acces the conents of a var but what the preprocessor can do is to calculate the number i want to divide through and the number i want to use with modulo. For example: 2 should be replaced by 10 and 3 should be replaced by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

*For example: 2 should be replaced by 10 and 3 should be replaced by 1000.*

It is written as follows using the boost.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/while.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/add.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>

#define PRED(d, state) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, state)

#define OP(d, state) (BOOST_PP_DEC(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, state)), BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, state), 0))

#define pow0(n) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, BOOST_PP_WHILE(PRED, OP, (BOOST_PP_ADD(n,1), 1)))

int main(void) {
    int n = pow0(2);//1000: "1" + "0"✕(n+1) 
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```